# Get table description via SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-schema

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2016, how do I query the table description property via SQL?  I'm doing some class generation automation and that's the last piece that I can't figure out. It was, surprisingly to me at least, not on the `sys.tables` table.

Comment: `sys.extended_properties`. It's not really part of the engine as such, but the special property named `MS_Description` is treated as the description by SSMS (and hence many third-party tools as well) on various levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t.name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.value)
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.extended_properties p ON t.object_id = p.major_id
WHERE t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' AND p.name = 'MS_Description' AND p.minor_id = 0 AND LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.value)) > 0
```